При создании страницы StaticPages вылазит ошибка
При создании страницы StaticPages вылазит ошибка
Создал шаблон в Winter Cms
useContent = 1
default = 0
==

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'assets/css/icomoon.css' | theme }}">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'assets/css/null.css' | theme }}">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ 'assets/css/style.css' | theme }}">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
   <title>{{ this.page.title }}</title>
   <style>
      @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
   </style>
</head>

<body>

   <div class="body-wrapper">
      {% partial "header" %}

      <main class="main">
         {% page %}
      </main>


      {% partial "footer.htm" %}
   </div>

   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/ui@5.0/dist/fancybox/fancybox.umd.js"></script>
   <script src="{{ 'assets/js/script.js' | theme }}"></script>
</body>

</html>

после этого создаю страницу staticPages

и вылазит ошибка
Too few arguments to function Twig\Environment::loadTemplate(), 1 passed in C:\OSPanel\domains\sosnovyibor\plugins\winter\pages\classes\Controller.php on line 81 and at least 2 expected
C:\OSPanel\domains\sosnovyibor\vendor\twig\twig\src\Environment.php line 330


В Controller.php изменить:
$template = $twig->loadTemplate($staticPage->getFilePath());

на:
$template = $twig->load($staticPage->getFilePath());


пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
